# GetByTitle('Pages')/items?$filter=Id eq xxx error

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

My service call has the following:

```
GetByTitle('Pages')/items?$filter=Id eq 19
```

which with the correct encoding is:

```
GetByTitle('Pages')/items?$filter=Id%20eq%2019
```

which returns me the following error:

```
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<m:code>
-2147024749, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQueryThrottledException
</m:code>
<m:message xml:lang="en-US">
```

> The query cannot be completed because the number of lookup columns it contains exceeds the lookup column threshold enforced by the administrator.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can add a select option to your rest call to specify the fields that you want. This can solve your problem if you don't want all the lookup fields. Have a look here about select: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385.aspx#sectionSection0

Comment: For reference: GetByTitle('Pages')/items?$select=Title,FileRef,PublishingPageLayout&$filter=Id%20eq%2019 It worked. Thank you for you help

Comment: How to resolve the issue for sharepoint online??

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the throttle from the Central Administration under Web Application Settings.

Comment: Not in SharePoint Online, which is what the question is tagged with.